# How can I fix the 'Some installed products need licenses' error during Siemens TIA Portal STEP 7 Professional V15.1 installation?

Tags: siemens, wincc

I'm trying to install Siemens TIA portal, but get a setup error. The setup states that "Some installed products need licenses", but shouldn't it just work with a trial license? The specific version I have is: TIA Portal STEP 7 Professional V15.1.

I completely removed SQL Server from the system, but the problem did not go away.

Log file:

```
2023.06.01 15:16:38 - Year.Month.Day - Log start

BUNDLE: SIMATIC TIA Portal STEP 7 Professional V15.1 - WinCC Professional V15.1
SEBU Version: Professional:TIA.rgs.RTM_15010000:V15.01.00.00_28.01.00.01

OS: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro Professional, 64-bit, build 19045
COMMANDLINE: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Siemens\Automation\Siemens Installer Assistant\406\sia2.exe /afterreboot /bundlepath=C:\USERS\---\DESKTOP\TIA\InstData /starter
INSTALLDIR: C:\Program Files\Siemens\Automation
SETUPLANGUAGE: 1033
PRODUCTLANGUAGES: 1033

CHANGES: (+)DotNet_Updater;(o)SQLNCLI;(+)INSTSQL2014EXP_SCADA;(+)SYMLINK;(+)SYMLINKADD;(+)OPCCORECOMP;(+)OPCCORECOMP64;(+)OPCNETAPI;(+)OPCNETAPI45;(+)NCMGPRS64;(+)NCMFWL64;(+)WinCC ACE;(+)WinCC Common Archiving;(+)OPC;(+)Runtime Interfaces;(+)HMIProvider;(+)SECON;(+)S7DOS64;(+)S7DOS;(+)S7EDB;(+)Automation Software Updater;(+)TIA_Portal;(+)MU_Client;(+)HWCN-HWCOL;(+)SUPBASEH02;(+)SUPBASEH03;(+)SUPBASEH04;(+)SUPBASETO01;(+)SUPBASETO02;(+)SUPBASEWCF01;(+)TIAP_SIMATIC;(+)TIAP_SIMATIC32;(+)STEP7;(+)WinCC Runtime Advanced Simulator;(+)PTSymLib;(+)PTTouchInput;(+)HM_AllEditions;(+)HM_NoBasic;(+)STOBS;(+)STOP_ALMSERVICE;(+)AlmPanelPlugin64;(+)Prosave;(+)TIA_ES;(+)TIA_ES32;(+)WinCC_Tr_Mandatory;(+)WinCC_TrC_All;(+)WinCC_TrC_CAP;(+)SCADA-RT;(+)RT_Pro_Sim;(+)TIACOMPCHECK;(+)OPCUA_Client;(+)TIAADMIN;(+)AWB_SOFT;(+)AWB_ALM;(+)AWB_TIAUMAC

There are NO severe messages before the installation


15:16:38 | BEGIN. Execution started.
15:16:50 | OK                        RunningProcesses           ()                          Complete
15:16:50 | OK                        InventoryBefore            (A)                         Complete
15:16:50 | OK                        Citamis                    (Before)                    Complete
15:17:09 | OK                        SecurityControlFeature     (ReturnFeatures)            Complete
15:17:09 | OK                        StartApplBefore            (TIAP15_1::[INSTALLDIR]BIN\SIEMENS.AUTOMATION.OBJECTFRAME.FILESTORAGE.SERVER.EXE)Complete
15:17:09 | OK                        StartApplBefore            (TIAP15_1::[INSTALLDIR]X64\BIN\SIEMENS.AUTOMATION.OBJECTFRAME.FILESTORAGE.SERVER.EXE)Complete
15:17:09 | OK                        ClassicCompPrepare         ()                          Complete
15:17:10 | OK                        ProductRegistration        (Before)                    Complete
15:17:10 | OK                        ClassicCompAfterUninstall  ()                          Complete
15:17:10 | OK                        SetupUnit                  (DotNet_Updater)            Complete  Foreign   AddLocal  
15:17:11 | OK                        Checkpoint                 (RE)                        Complete
15:17:12 | OK                        SetupUnit                  (SQLNCLI)                   Complete  Foreign   Reinstall 
15:17:13 | OK                        Checkpoint                 (E)                         Complete
15:17:14 |ERROR    AdsWorkerClassicProduct::OnWorkerCompleted():  - ClassicProduct setup failed due to unknown error
15:17:14 | FAIL!                     SetupUnit                  (INSTSQL2014EXP_SCADA)      Failed    ClassicProductAddLocal  
15:17:14 | FAIL!                     Checkpoint                 (E)                         Complete
15:17:14 |ERROR    ExecutionEngine::StartNextStepAsync():  - Execution has been cancelled. Probably because of some process(es) running on the machine
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SYMLINK)                   Skip      Foreign   AddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SYMLINKADD)                Skip      Foreign   AddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (OPCCORECOMP)               Skip      Foreign   AddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (OPCCORECOMP64)             Skip      Foreign   AddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (OPCNETAPI)                 Skip      Foreign   AddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (OPCNETAPI45)               Skip      Foreign   AddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (NCMGPRS64)                 Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (NCMFWL64)                  Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (WinCC ACE)                 Skip
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (WinCC ACE)                 Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (WinCC ACE)                 Skip
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (WinCC Common Archiving)    Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (OPC)                       Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (Runtime Interfaces)        Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (HMIProvider)               Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SECON)                     Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (S7DOS64)                   Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (S7DOS)                     Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (S7EDB)                     Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (Automation Software Updater)Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (TIA_Portal)                Skip
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (TIA_Portal)                Skip      PlusMain  AddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (TIA_Portal)                Skip
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (MU_Client)                 Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (HWCN-HWCOL)                Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SUPBASEH02)                Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SUPBASEH03)                Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SUPBASEH04)                Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SUPBASETO01)               Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SUPBASETO02)               Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SUPBASEWCF01)              Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (TIAP_SIMATIC)              Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (TIAP_SIMATIC32)            Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (STEP7)                     Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (WinCC Runtime Advanced Simulator)Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (PTSymLib)                  Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (PTTouchInput)              Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (HM_AllEditions)            Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (HM_NoBasic)                Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (STOBS)                     Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (STOP_ALMSERVICE)           Skip      Foreign   AddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (AlmPanelPlugin64)          Skip      ClassicComponentAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (Prosave)                   Skip      ClassicProductAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (TIA_ES)                    Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (TIA_ES32)                  Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (WinCC_Tr_Mandatory)        Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (WinCC_TrC_All)             Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (WinCC_TrC_CAP)             Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (SCADA-RT)                  Skip
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (SCADA-RT)                  Skip      PlusMain  AddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (SCADA-RT)                  Skip
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (RT_Pro_Sim)                Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (TIACOMPCHECK)              Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (OPCUA_Client)              Skip
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (OPCUA_Client)              Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SecurityControl            (OPCUA_Client)              Skip
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (TIAADMIN)                  Skip      PlusMain  AddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (AWB_SOFT)                  Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (AWB_ALM)                   Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupUnit                  (AWB_TIAUMAC)               Skip      PlusOptionalAddLocal  
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     ClassicCompAfterInstall    ()                          Skip
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     ClassicCompRollback        ()                          Skip
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     HspInstall                 ()                          Skip
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     MspInstall                 ()                          Skip
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     StartApplAfter             (TIAP15_1::[INSTALLDIR]BIN\INSTALLROOTCERTIFICATE.EXE)Skip
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     StartApplAfter             (TIAP15_1::[INSTALLDIR]BIN\SIEMENS.AUTOMATION.GENERATOR.FRAMEWORK.EXE)Skip
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     StartApplAfter             (TIAP15_1::C:\WINDOWS\SYSWOW64\S7EPATSX.EXE)Skip
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     StartApplAfter             (TIAP15_1::C:\WINDOWS\SYSWOW64\S7EPAESX.EXE)Skip
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     StartApplAfter             (TIAP15_1::[INSTALLDIR]BIN\SIEMENS.SIMATIC.HWCN.INTERPRETER.IG.GSD.GENERATOR.EXE)Skip
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     ProductRegistration        (After)                     Skip
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     InventoryAfter             (Z)                         Skip
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     LicenseTransfer            (False)                     Skip
15:17:14 | SKIP!                     SetupReport                ()                          Skip
15:17:16 | OK                        SetupIsComplete            ()                          Complete
15:17:16 | OK                        Citamis                    (After)                     Complete
15:17:16 | OK                        SetupSummary               ()                          Complete
15:17:16 | END. Execution completed.

Intermediate ExitCode after execution queue : 1603 - Exit code means: Installation failed (InstallFailure)
Errors: 2
Warnings: 0
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Do you have other Tia Portal Professional version installed?, you can have just one Professional version installed. Check https://support.industry.siemens.com/forum/de/en/posts/installing-multiple-versions-of-tia-portal-wincc-flexible/171421

Comment: No, there is no other siemens program. The computer was formatted, and after installing standard programs (such as chrome, adobe, winrar), I started to install siemens programs.